# Script troubleshooting

Tags: key, activation

I'm trying my hand at AHK and want to make it load up all of the things for when I play runescape. I have no idea what's up with my first script, so if someone could point out what is up with it, I would be eternally greatful. Here is the script.

```
#r::Run C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\runescape.exe
Run C:\Program Files (x86)\Mumble\mumble.exe
Run C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\spotify.exe
Run www.google.com
Run www.zybez.com
Run www.reddit.com
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#r::
Run C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\runescape.exe
Run C:\Program Files (x86)\Mumble\mumble.exe
Run C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\spotify.exe
Run http://www.google.com
Run http://www.zybez.com
Run http://www.reddit.com
return
```

Don't put stuff on the same line as the hotkey.
You might also need to add http:// to the urls.